# Ubuntu 22.04 dhcpd restart on docking station interface reconnect

Tags: usb, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhcpcd

I have setup on my desk, where Ethernet connected device is plugged into port of my USB-C docking station (same that powers the notebook). I've configured `isc-dhcpd` to work on `enx3ce1a14ec0bd` interface, what works... until it doesn't.

I disconnect my power supply overnight and put the machine to sleep (hibernation not configured yet). But that shuts down the docking station and as it's USB device the Ethernet port is disconnected from the system.

When I turn it on again in the morning, the port is back, but `isc-dhcpd` doesn't listen on `enx3ce1a14ec0bd` and the last message in the journal is (Polish locale):

```
sty 25 22:31:23 norah dhcpd[3578682]: receive_packet failed on enx3ce1a14ec0bd: Network is down
```

I had to restart the daemon manually (`systemctl restart`) to get it working.

Now, the **question** is how to set up a `isc-dhcpd` restart (of fix the problem other way) when the USB Ethernet comes back to life?

Comment: Does adding **Restart=on-failure** as part of the [service] section of isc-dhcp-server.service help ? (Possibly adding a **RestartSec=3** condition)

Comment: @MC68020 the `systemctl status isc-dhcpd` shows `active (running)` even after the interface error is reported, so it doesn't exit on that error.

Comment: You might to make the service BindsTo= and WantedBy= the device unit. (Or *maybe* a udev rule that restarts the service on the add action, if you prefer.)